# Can a player return a card to discard pile if they are still touching it?

Tags: phase-10

My family believes that you may pick up a card from the discard pile and return it, as long as you are still touching the card, and **then** draw From the draw pile in the same turn. I disagree and think once the card is picked up it is yours to keep or discard and end your turn.

What is the correct rule?

Answer (score 2):

TL;DR : They are technically breaking the rules but you should allow it as it doesn't affect the game.

Looking at the rules [here](https://www.unorules.com/phase-10-rules/) it says :-

> Draw a card from either the Draw Pile or the Discard Pile, and add it
>   to your hand. And then, discard any card that you want onto the
>   Discard Pile.

There is also nothing in the rules about 'still touching' anywhere that I can see.  So technically the answer to your question is no that is not allowed.

However, there is also an answer about just being nice person when playing games.  If a player picks up a publicly visible discard and decides that is not what they want to do, and the next player has not taken a turn, I see no good reason why they shouldn't put it be back and be able to draw a card.  Nothing has changed that can not be undone.  No new information was available.

Of course if a player drew a card from the deck and saw it then that would have to stick and shouldn't be returned as they have new information that was not available at the start of the turn.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you all agree on the rule on drawing from either one pile or the other, but you disagree on what constitutes a drawing of a card from a pile (or stated another way: whether physically examining the card on the discard pile constitutes "drawing" that card).

Since either definition is suitable (though one may be more common than the other), and since choosing one over the other has no effect on the game, just agree on a definition and play the game.